# How do I change the stroke color for polylines?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

My web app allows users to draw polylines on them. I want to give users the option to change the polyline's stroke color.

I looked at the polyline object in console log. In the options property, there is a property called color. I have tried this.

```
selectedLayer.options.color = "#2196F3";
```

And this.

```
selectedLayer.color = "#2196F3";
```

And this.

```
selectedLayer.setStyle({ color: "#2196F3"});
```

The stroke color should have changed, but it does not. What is the proper way to set a polyline's stroke color after it has been created? As far as I know, this is not an issue with polygon's fillColor property.

Comment: I suggest you check the [documentation about `L.Polyline`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#polyline) instead of `console.log()`ing stuff at random.

Answer (score 6):

Use latest version of leaflet which is 1.5. The code below will work for you.

```
var polyline = new L.Polyline([
  [-45, 45],
  [45, -45]
], {
  color: 'green',
  weight: 5,
  opacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
polyline.setStyle({color:'#2196F3'});
```

[image: Green Color which is set initially has been replaced by the color you have mentioned]

Comment: Latest version is 1.5.1

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`css variables`](https://css-tricks.com/updating-a-css-variable-with-javascript/) for that. 
Take a look at the following example:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
document.querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', () => {
    div.style.setProperty('--line-color', 'green');
  });
```

```css
:root {
  --line-color: red;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid var(--line-color);
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world</div>

<button>Change color to green</button>
```